# How to add multiple source members with main into the same Objective C project in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I am currently learning Objective C programming using Xcode. I am wondering how to have multiple main programs, i.e. source members with main method in it, in a single project? It is a bit inconvienient to put just one in each project, as I would have to create tons of them through my learning process. Or is there any better way to do it? All I want is to place multiple independent executable programs in a single project, though I only need to run on each time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much more trouble than it's worth. Just create tiny test projects. I've got a huge directory of them that I throw away from time to time. I also constantly re-create a project called "Test" for building little projects.

For really, really tiny things, I do sometimes create a simple `test.m` file that has its own `main` and compile it by hand:

```
gcc -framework Foundation -o test test.m
```

But in that case I don't bother with Xcode.

**EDIT** You of course could replace `gcc` above with `clang`. For projects so small that I'm doing this, it hasn't been worth changing my muscle memory....

Comment: I have a similar setup with many test projects. I'm too lazy to use the command line compiler, though. <g>

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy. I was looking for a method to compile and run Objective C on terminal and now you have provided me with the proper way. I can leave Xcode for a while until I have enough knowledge to start a proper iOS project.

Answer (score 1):

Each target can have a maximum of one `main()` method.  So you need to create a different target for each program and put each `main()` into a different source file.  Each source file with a `main()` in it can be comiled into only one target.

Answer (score 0):

If your mini-projects are simple enough you could also put it all in one project, creating classes/methods for each subject that you would otherwise have created a new project for.

It could be a class "Experiments" or "Learning" with methods like "experimentWithSomeStuff" or "testSomething". You could instantiate this class in main and call just the method you are working on at the moment.

I did this when I learned ObjC-Basics and it worked fine for me.
This way you can quickly check your "older" experiments to refresh how something works.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can make many applications, lets called them that, in the same Xcode project by creating new targets, and to test them individually, you just need to go to `Product-> Manage schemes` and choose the target you want to build and run.

I guess then Xcode runs the main associated to that target.